# SQL Server: Currency Converter Function

Tags: sql-server

The function I have created which will convert any currency to £ POUND Sterling. Indeed any currency is limited to what is defined in the function.

The function is created fine but when I am using it in a select statement on a field to give me a rate based on wither the region is UK/UAE/JAP etc

I get the following error:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 2
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.

The logic is fine, how do I get through the data type please?

Select statement to use the function

```
SELECT RegionCode
      ,VALUE
     ,[dbo].[fnCurrencyConvertee](RegionCode) * VALUE
  FROM temp.dbo.Treasurey
```

Function code --**IMPORTANT NOTE, THE FOLLOWING CODE IS NOW CORRECT AND WORKS AWESOME, THANKS TO EVERYONE'S CONTRIBUTION**

```
USE [temp]
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[zsCurrencyConvertee] 
     (@inPutRegionCode_column VARCHAR(5))
RETURNS DECIMAL(38,2)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Convert DECIMAL(20,2)
    DECLARE @Default DECIMAL(20,2) --Default currency is £,

    DECLARE @UK DECIMAL(20,2)
    DECLARE @TURK DECIMAL(20,2) --TURKEY
    DECLARE @AFG DECIMAL(20,2)
    DECLARE @MEX DECIMAL(20,2) --MEXICO
    DECLARE @MOR DECIMAL(20,2) --MOROCCO
    DECLARE @UAE DECIMAL(20,2)
    DECLARE @IRA DECIMAL(38,2) --IRAQ
    DECLARE @JAP DECIMAL(20,2)
    DECLARE @CHI DECIMAL(20,2)

    SET @Convert = 0.00 --Variable which will be reused to hold converted values
    SET @Default = 1.00 --Reset this value if the conversion is required between other currencies such as UAE to JAPANESE etc

    SET @UK = 1
    SET @TURK = 6.87
    SET @AFG = 97.58
    SET @MEX = 24.69
    SET @MOR = 12.31
    SET @UAE = 4.73
    SET @IRA = 1536.43
    SET @JAP = 141.15
    SET @CHI = 8.75

    BEGIN
            IF(@inPutRegionCode_column = 'UK')
            BEGIN
                SET @Convert = @Default / @UK
            END
            ELSE IF(@inPutRegionCode_column = 'TURK')
            BEGIN
                SET @Convert = @Default / @TURK
            END
            ELSE IF(@inPutRegionCode_column = 'AFG')
            BEGIN
                SET @Convert = @Default / @AFG
            END
            ELSE IF(@inPutRegionCode_column = 'MEX')
            BEGIN
                SET @Convert = @Default / @MEX
            END
            ELSE IF(@inPutRegionCode_column = 'MOR')
            BEGIN
                SET @Convert = @Default / @MOR
            END
            ELSE IF(@inPutRegionCode_column = 'UAE')
            BEGIN
                SET @Convert = @Default / @UAE
            END
            ELSE IF(@inPutRegionCode_column = 'IRA')
            BEGIN
                SET @Convert = @Default / @IRA
            END
            ELSE IF(@inPutRegionCode_column = 'JAP')
            BEGIN
                SET @Convert = @Default / @JAP
            END
            ELSE IF(@inPutRegionCode_column = 'CHI')
            BEGIN
                SET @Convert = @Default / @CHI
            END
    END
RETURN
    @Convert
END
```

]

Table if you may need it

```
USE [temp]
GO
CREATE TABLE Treasurey
(
    RegionCode VARCHAR(5),
    Value INT
)

INSERT [dbo].[Treasurey] ([RegionCode], [Value]) VALUES (N'TURK', 23)
INSERT [dbo].[Treasurey] ([RegionCode], [Value]) VALUES (N'AFG', 55)
INSERT [dbo].[Treasurey] ([RegionCode], [Value]) VALUES (N'UK', 33)
INSERT [dbo].[Treasurey] ([RegionCode], [Value]) VALUES (N'MOR', 100)
INSERT [dbo].[Treasurey] ([RegionCode], [Value]) VALUES (N'UAE', 150)
INSERT [dbo].[Treasurey] ([RegionCode], [Value]) VALUES (N'IRA', 200)
INSERT [dbo].[Treasurey] ([RegionCode], [Value]) VALUES (N'JAP', 23)
INSERT [dbo].[Treasurey] ([RegionCode], [Value]) VALUES (N'CHI', 49)
```

Comment: All your currencies are defined as a `decimal(2,2)`. Try `DECLARE @d decimal(2,2); SET @d = 1;` and youre quickly see ever that is too large. If you look further down, you're expecting a value like `1536.43` to fit in a data type that can has a precision of 2 digits; that's never going to fit. Use appropriate datatype precision and scales.

Comment: very nice, could you help with a data that would support 2 decimals and at least 2000 as a whole number.

Comment: Have a look as Scsimon's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `decimal (2,2)` which means the largest number you can fit in there is 0.99. However, you are trying to put larger number in.

```
DECLARE @IRA DECIMAL(2,2) --IRAQ
SET @IRA = 1536.43
```

Make your variable declarations larger. At least `decimal(6,2)` based on this sample data... but you may need to go much larger `decimal(38,2)` for example to account for lager numeric ranges.

```
DECLARE @IRA DECIMAL(6,2) --IRAQ
SET @IRA = 1536.43
```

See more on [precision, scale, and length.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: You'll probably want to make `@Convert` even larger since you are multiplying. Just a thought.

Comment: That was an error it should be divided. I corrected it. check now :) so it gets smaller since pound is high than multiplied by a value